# Elastic Beanstalk SSL not working with hosts file mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment with an SSL certificate that works if I visit the *.elasticbeanstalk.com URL (with a warning from by browser). For testing purposes I've mapped the IP of the instance to the domain in my hosts file before I change nameservers over. However when I try the actual URL with https:// I got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from Chrome - http:// works fine though. I've flushed the DNS cache and I know DNS shouldn't care about application layer protocols - so I'm pretty stumped here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is disabled by default on new elastic beanstalk environments.
If it's a single server environment, you'd need to setup SSL yourself ([documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSL.SingleInstance.html)).
If it's a load balanced one, simply enable the HTTPS protocol in the ElasticBeanstalk web console (*Configuration => Network Tier => Load Balancing => Load Balancer*)

Comment: It's load balanced and I've enabled HTTPS on 443 and opened the ports on the EC2 instances.

Comment: HTTPS is enabled for the load balancer and not the actual instance. You may have opened port 443 on the instance, but the nginx there is not listening as it's used to get its traffic over 80 from the load balancer. You should probably set a CNAME that points to the *.elasticbeanstalk.com URL rather than the instance IP. Alternatively you can configure nginx to listen to traffic on 443.